# Xdebug successfully connects to DBGP clients, but won't stop at breakpoints

Tags: php, netbeans, debugging, breakpoints, xdebug

I have [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) 2.1 installed, and running with PHP 5.2.13.  It can successfully connect to multiple DBGP clients (i.e. the `xdebug.remote_log` shows communication back and forth, and the clients themselves also show the incoming connection), but it doesn't stop at breakpoints.  I have tried [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/), [MacGDBp](http://www.bluestatic.org/software/macgdbp/) and also the command-line [`debugclient`](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote) bundled with Xdebug.

A typical exchange looks like:

```
Log opened at 2010-07-20 09:33:17
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///mnt/hgfs/htdocs/mycompany/index.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="14371" idekey="macgdbp"><engine version="2.1.0"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2010 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- status -i macgdbp
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="macgdbp" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

<- step_into -i macgdbp
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="macgdbp" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

<- status -i macgdbp
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="macgdbp" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2010-07-20 09:33:18
```

NetBeans attempts to set breakpoints, and these are acknowledged by Xdebug:

```
<- breakpoint_set -i 7 -t line -s enabled -f file:///mnt/hgfs/htdocs/mycompany/index.php -n 9
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="7" state="enabled" id="139360004"></response>
```

However, Xdebug still refuses to stop!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This appears to happen if you have have Xdebug loaded as an `extension` (i.e. `extension=xdebug.so`) in the PHP config instead of a `zend_extension` (i.e. `zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20060613+lfs/xdebug.so`).

**Make sure that you don't have an `extension=xdebug.so` line *anywhere* in your PHP config**, even if you're pretty sure you're using `zend_extension`.  For example, if you have `zend_extension` in `/etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini`, this may well be superseded by an `extension` in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`.  If this is the case, nothing will complain, and `phpinfo()` will dutifully report that Xdebug is loaded!  (Xdebug 2.1 does issue a small warning in `phpinfo()` when loaded as an extension, but previous versions do nothing.)

Comment: Wow, this really saved me after getting some weird behavior configuring remote debugging with MacGDBP. I could see that connections were successful in the xdebug.remote_log, and the client was receiving connections, but connections were quickly being dropped. There was no output in the client either. Changed "extension=xdebug.so" as you suggested and boom everything works beautifully.

Comment: You sir made my day. If I could, I would upvote a thousand times.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on Docker container on Windows. All seemed properly configured, phpStorm properly listening on local port 9000 on 127.0.0.1. phpinfo() displayed the xdebug.so running. When I run the script from the web browser, **the debugger failed to stop on the breakopint**. The xdebug.log contained this:

```
Log opened at 2019-07-02 08:17:10
I: Connecting to configured address/port: docker.for.mac.localhost:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///app/www/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.2.15" protocol_version="1.0" appid="38768" idekey="PHPSTORM"><engine version="2.6.1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2018 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2019-07-02 08:17:10
```

I had to ssh into the container to find out that it wasn't connecting out from the container to the Windows, which hosted the container. The problem was, that my docker compose configuration contained `docker.for.mac.localhost` which was about to be set into the `xdebug.remote_host` setting. Even if the xdebug.log claimed xdebug connected to the client, in fact it didn't connect.

**The solution was `xdebug.remote_host = host.docker.internal`.**
This hostname is used in Docker container to make a local connection to the operating system which is hosting the container.

More info here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/

Comment: Finally!!!  After days of trying to figure out the issue!  My issue was that I had xdebug.discover_client_host enabled and I did not specify xdebug.client_host.  I disabled discover_client_host and set client_host=host.docker.internal.

Answer (score 1):

If php files are placed into symlink-folder then XDebug will operate with source folder path instead of symlink-folder path!

So to enable breakpoints you should configure path mappings in your ide for symlinked folders and files

Answer (score 0):

You must add the **full path** to the `xdebug.so` file, even when it's placed in the `php/modules/` folder, as `zend_extension` doesn't looks in this folder by default.

If you have an `exension=xdebug.so` line, xdebug will load but it won't stop at breakpoints (beats me why).

Removing all `exension=xdeabug.so` (even from the cli ini file, which also loads) and adding the `zend_extension` will solve the issue.

Comment: this just repeat everything that's said by @mjs... An answer to a question which is 2 years old should be better than this.

Comment: I was just clarifying that you must use the full path, he says "zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20060613+lfs/xdebug.so" but I assumed he used this path because he had a compiled version there or whatever, as I put the xdebug.so in the php/modules folder I didn't put the full path (as you do with the "extension" directive) and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this has been answered but I came across the same issue just want to offer my answer if anyone else runs across this. I accidentally missed a case value in my paths which still allowed me to connect and run the debugger but it wouldn't stop at my breakpoints. I didn't realized it till much frustration so I just want people to know that that could be a possibility as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Eclipse can't pick up the debug info, so enable xdebug log and check the response, returned 
    `<response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>` with no more info.

Fix is to change debug configure

```
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 to
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
```

in /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini

then restart Apache.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey, I am also getting the same in the xdebug logs. But your solution is not working for me. I am using Netbeans and Code is in Remotehost Cent OS 7. 
Any help would be appreciated.