# Vagrant with XDebug and Sublime Text: don´t stop at breakpoints

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, xdebug, vagrant

I have problems with debugging with Sublime Text 2, Vagrant and XDebug. The debug don't stop at breakpoints

I use this vagrant box https://github.com/bryannielsen/Laravel4-Vagrant

I´ve read a lot of questions in StackOverflow and none has the answer for my problem.
[Xdebug successfully connects to DBGP clients, but won't stop at breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288840/xdebug-successfully-connects-to-dbgp-clients-but-wont-stop-at-breakpoints) tells about don´t use xdebug as a module, and I'm using as extension. It seems ok! Others talk about the php.ini configuration but my log seems good

When start the xdebug in sublimetext (with https://github.com/Kindari/SublimeXdebug) it launchs the webpage fine, but sublime shows a message: waiting for execute and not stop at the breakpoints and the webpage is full loaded

My xdebug log looks fine

```
Log opened at 2013-09-25 12:01:56
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 10.0.2.2:9001.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/public/index.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="14735" idekey="sublime.xdebug"><engine version="2.2.3"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2013 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2013-09-25 12:01:56
```

Sublime text 2 is waiting to listen on port 9001 and it is my php.ini configuration

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_log=tmp/xdebug.log
```

Someone have experience with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it with Sublime. (Actually I was googling whether it's possible and landed to this page :)

Anyway, I'll try to help you. I had a similar issue with NetBeans and I found that xDebug won't make a call back if you do not specify the remote host. That was a reason why NetBeans didn't stop at any breakpoint, it simply didn't get any response from xDebug.

Try adding to your php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_host = 10.0.2.2
```

My xdebug.ini on the VM looks like this:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_host = 10.0.2.2
```

P.S. Also make sure those settings are populated when you do a phpinfo().