# NetBeans + XDebug Breakpoints not working

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, xdebug

I know there are countless of questions regarding this subject, however no matter what I've tried I've had no luck whatsoever. The problem I'm encountering is regarding breakpoints when using NetBeans and XDebug (on Windows 8.1 if that affects anything).

The issue is that no breakpoints are working. By default when debugging with NetBeans, it stops on the first line and this does successfully happen. Therefore NetBeans is somehow connecting to XDebug. However, any other breakpoints in any other files are not working.

I've tried various different settings in the php.ini file but no luck so far. I've also tried switching on the XDebug log file so that maybe I can analyse what's going on, but this also didn't work. Finally I've tried setting breakpoints using `xdebug_break()` which also didn't work.

**XDebug settings in php.ini**

```
;[XDebug]
; Only Zend OR (!) XDebug
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"
```

**Project Run Configuration on NetBeans**

[image: Project Run Configuration]

[image: Advanced Configuration]

*I've already looked at the following:*

- http://articlebin.michaelmilette.com/making-xdebug-work-with-netbeans-on-windows/
- [Xdebug ignores breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422433/xdebug-ignores-breakpoints)
- http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug#Tips_from_the_NetBeans_Forums

Also note that this was working 3 days ago, however today no breakpoints are working.

**Additional Info**

I've run the following command in cmd `php -v` and the following warning was shown:

`Warning: Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0`

Does this mean that xdebug is trying to be loaded twice? If so I'm not sure how this can be solved

Answer (score 4):

Figured out what the problem was. I know that this answer will be very specific, however it might help someone in the future.

So while inspecting the code I noticed that someone added code that cleared all cookies when the login page loaded. Once the cookies are removed XDebug didn't work. The reason is that for XDebug to work it sets a cookie with the session id for example 'netbeans-xdebug' which is sent with every request on the website.

It's a very simple issue but it took nearly 2 days to find out what was going on. Once again I know that this is a very specific case but maybe it might help someone out there.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you!! I never would have guessed that the problem could have been with cookies if not for this post. By switching to using the GET arg `?XDEBUG_START_SESSION=ide_key`, instead of the `XDEBUG_SESSION=ide_key` cookie, I was able to get my breakpoints to work!

Comment: @CoreDumpError you're welcome!! Happy that this helped someone after all this time :D